# What type of proof is $P\Rightarrow P$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have this problem statement:

Let $P$ a proposition, now if we suppose $P$ is $\texttt{true}$, and the proof gives $P$. What demonstrates this?

**Solution:**

$\ \  P\Rightarrow P$

$\equiv \langle \texttt{Definition }\Rightarrow\rangle$

$\ \  \neg P \vee P$

$\equiv \langle \texttt{Law of excluded middle} \rangle$

$\ \  true$

Therefore,

$P\Rightarrow P \equiv true$

***But***, I'm wandering if this is proving something? Or it just only shows how to apply the *law of excluded middle*?

Comment: “$P\Rightarrow P$” is a tautology, so it proves nothing. For instance ”$0\ne1\Rightarrow 0\ne1$” is surely true, but says nothing about the truth of “$0\ne1$”.

Comment: @egreg, what name can receive this type of *proof*?

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdoñez You have proved that “$P\Rightarrow P$” is a tautology.

Answer (score 2):

We have proved the [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)):

$P \to P$,

i.e. a formula (or *schema*) of truth-functional [sentential logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) that is always *true*, i.e. *true* in every possible interpretation.

In other terms, whatever is the natural language *sentence* that we can use to interpret the [sentential letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_variable) (or variable) $P$, the "complex" sentence we will get is true.

Interpreting $P$ with the sentence:

> "The snow is white",

the "complex" sentence:

> "**if** the snow is white, **then** the snow is white"

is *true*.

And the same with "The sky is green", due to the truth-functional condition for $\to$ (i.e. $FALSE \to FALSE$ is $TRUE$).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to prove $P \Rightarrow P$.

1. Use a [truth table](https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html):

[image]

The proof that this statement is a tautology comes from the column in red: all rows in that column are true.

2. Use a [derivation system](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) with inference rules:

[image]

There are two inference rules used in this Fitch-style proof checker after an assumption is made on line 1. One is called [reiteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem#Virtual_rules_of_inference) (R) where a statement that one already accepts may be used again. The second rule is conditional introduction (→I). This rule summarizes the subproof on lines 2 and 3: if I assume $P$ is true then any line correctly derived after that can be used as a conclusion. It is also called the [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem).

---

Here is the OP's question:

> But, I'm wandering if this is proving something? Or it just only shows how to apply the law of excluded middle?

In the truth table one can see that any statement $P$ can have one of two truth values, true or false. That would be the [principle of bivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_bivalence). The [law of excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) claims that any statement $P$ is either true or $\lnot P$ is true which would be useful in a derivation.

The derivation doesn't use the law of excluded middle as an inference rule to derive $P \Rightarrow P$. Admittedly, this derived conditional doesn't show much. However, one can look at $P$ as the common ground for two people engaging in an argument. After arguing they may be no further than $P$. Then all they can claim is $P \Rightarrow P$.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Michael Rieppel Truth Table Generator https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html